# npm s3 --> https://www.npmjs.org/package/s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm

I am trying to upload an image to my s3 bucket using the npm s3 module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/s3)

I used the following params

```
var params = {
localFile: 'image.png',

s3Params: {
    Bucket: 'newstie.com',
    Key: '/newsite/image'
}
};
```

And I am getting the following logs and I wasn't able to understand what I did wrong. Can you please help me? Many Thanks

progress 12181 0 12181
progress 12181 12181 12181
unable to upload Error
at Request.extractError (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:257:35)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:114:20)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:16)
at Request.emit (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:81:10)
at Request.emit (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:578:14)
at Request.transition (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:12:12)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:28:10
at Request. (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:28:9)
at Request. (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:580:12)
progress 12181 0 12181
progress 12181 12181 12181
unable to upload Error
at Request.extractError (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:257:35)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:114:20)
at Request.callListeners (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:16)
at Request.emit (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:81:10)
at Request.emit (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:578:14)
at Request.transition (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:12:12)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:28:10
at Request. (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:28:9)
at Request. (/Users/Desktop/newsite/node_modules/s3/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:580:12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we need more code. I'm recommending using the [aws-sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/). Works perfectly, easy to upload, sync, trigger jobs and so on.

But to answer your question and assuming the file you're trying to upload is located in the same directory as your script your code would look something like this:

```
var params = {
  localFile: __dirname + '/image.png',

  s3Params: {
    Bucket: 'newstie.com',
    Key: '/newsite/image'
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi fresla. I didn't get a notification in my email, that's the reason I took to long to answer you. It worked! Many Thanks!